# Flutter Positioned Widget not fixed depending size screen

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, flutter-positioned, flutter-assetimage

My problem concerns the `Positioned` Widget. I'd like to position `Widget`s that match with an `ExactAssetImage` location of a `Container`. The context is to apply a PDF sheet to mobile with many assets with a `RadioButton`/editText.

The fact is, if I don't specify a fixed width and height for the `Container` containing the image, the `Positioned` `Widget` will not have the same position but it will depend on the size screen of the device.

This means I can't use `MediaQuery` to force my `Image` to fill the screen.

Here's my `Container` with the `Image`:

```
class CustomDecoratedBox extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget widget;
  final double width;
  final double height;
  String asset;

  CustomDecoratedBox({@required this.widget, this.height, this.width,this.asset});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0, vertical: 5.0),
      child: Container(
        width: width,
        height: height,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
              image: ExactAssetImage(
                asset,
              ),
             fit: BoxFit.fill,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
            ),
            border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
            color: Colors.white),
        child: widget,),);}
```

And here's how i position the child's positioned widget (whithin a stack because the are plenty of it):

```
return CustomDecoratedBox(
          width: 360,
          height: 360,
          asset: 'assets/xxx.png',
          widget: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                bottom: 12,
                left: 16,
                child: CustomTextFieldSetup(
                  width: 50,
                  maxLength: 5,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                  textEditingController: _textEditingController,
                ),
              ),
```

What would be according to you, the best way to answer this use case?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In your CustomDecoratedBox class, try wrapping the container in a FittedBox widget. FittedBox should scale your container within the constraints of your screen size and, in doing so, retain your positions relative to the container dimensions.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: Hi, Sorry for the delay. yes I've tried to wrap in a FittedBox, but with no success. I still have a gap between différent screen size. i'll let you know if i found a way. Thx

Comment: find a way that works fine. I don't know if it's the right way  but the result is here. Let me know what you think about it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found a very good way that works for every size of screen with the LayoutBuilder. What I did is **encapsulating 2 LayoutBuilder** in each other.

The child one will base its constraints on its parent LayoutBuilder. but the trick is the width and the height you give to your parent, as it has the image in its decoration, you should use only maxWidth or maxHeight to provide the dimension, based on the ratio dimen of your image :

```
return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, cons) => Center(
        child: Container(
  /// Here you size the container with the width for both height and width of 
  /// the container
          height: cons.maxWidth * 0.8839,
          width: cons.maxWidth,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage('assets/xxx.png'),
                fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
              ),
              border: Border.all(color: Colors.black, width: 1),
              color: Colors.white),
          child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, constraints) {
            double diameter = constraints.maxWidth / 28;
            return Center(
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                   Positioned(
                    top: constraints.maxHeight / 3.45,
                    right: constraints.maxWidth / 28,
                    child: //ect...
```

then you give to your Positionned widgets params constraint value.
Hope it will help for some of you